# Ubuntu (16.04 LTS 64-bit) keeps disconnections from WiFi

Tags: wireless

I installed Ubuntu on my PC, updated everything and it seemed everything will be fine.

But WiFi keeps disconnecting.
When PC is just turned on everything is fine, signal is strong and everything works as should.

But then it just disconnects, at random times. 
Sometimes after 3 minutes, sometimes after 10.

That little drop down menu you get when clicking on WiFi signal also sometimes gets mostly grayed out, you can't select "connect to hidden WiFi" for example.

Other times it's not grayed out, it's just constantly trying to reconnect without success. Rebooting is the only option.

I don't know anything about Ubuntu, or Linux in general. I tried googling, but every solution starts with terminal and a lot of commands which I'm not comfortable trying out since I have no idea what they do. I might mess up things even more.

Like I was saying, I did see that you guys usually ask for several commands and results, so I did that and here they are listed. I hope this can be solved.

Link to results:
https://pastebin.com/6BEJkNX8

Link to script results from [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108) : https://pastebin.com/Bs9KC6hq

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not a solution, but when I have a similar problem, I found that executing these two commands will get the wifi restarted without rebooting.

`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`
and 
`sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart`

These commands just restart the networking.